sjPlot- plot_model: how do I adjust my y axis?
I'm plotting 3 continuous variables (pland_herb, PD_woody, PD_herb) with my response variable which is Richness. I want to show the 3-way interaction that is occurring over 3 panels, same as this example below:
3-way interaction graph from regression model
However, I'm using a different code to get it:

plot_model(mod81, type = "int", mdrt.values = "all", terms = c("PD_Woody","PD_Herbaceous", "Pland_Herbaceous"))
Here is the resulting graph:
3-way interaction graph-messed up
How do I change the y-axis for the range of numbers to be much smaller? They're only from 0-45, not in the 1000's.
I also tried changing each of the 'type' options and that didn't fix anything.
I found another person's answer by Allen Cameron, which is almost helpful, however I don't want percentage, just whole numbers: Editing the y axis on a sjplot in R (plot_model)
How can I alter that code?
Any help is appreciated! Thank you

I've tinkered with ggeffects code instead and got a plot closer to what I want! Hooray!
Here is the code:
dat_categorical <- predict_response(mod81, terms = c("PD_Woody","PD_Herbaceous [-1, 0, 1]", "Pland_Herbaceous [-1, 0, 1]"))
plot(dat_categorical, breaks = seq(0, 22, 2), limits = c(0, 22), ci_style = "ribbon")

corrected 3-way interaction plot!
Now my question is how do I fix the confidence interval ribbons, that seem to be stopping in the left and right panel?
Thanks again

You set the y-limits to 0-22 (limits = c(0, 22)). The intervals seems to exceed this range and it therefore cropped. Just expand the y-axis range to a limit that includes the confidence interval limits and it should work.

Thanks for the suggestion Daniel. My y-axis is limited to see the details of interaction. If I expand it I loose the details of the interaction. Is there a way to change the code so I can make sure the confidence interval will follow the entire length of the line. Otherwise it looks like there is no confidence in my lines, or it stops.
Let me know! Thank you

Have you tried adding a ggplot2::coord_cartesian()?

Actually I ended finding a card_cartesian()  and my lab mate also suggested, and it worked! Thank you for validating that! Appreciate your help   '''dat_categorical61 <- predict_response(mod6, terms = c("PD_Woody", "PD_Herbaceous [-1, 0, 1]","Percent_Herbaceous [-1, 0, 1]"))
plot(dat_categorical61, ci_style = "ribbon") + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-1.5, 1.5),ylim = c(0,10),expand = TRUE, default = FALSE, clip = "on") + labs(
x = "Patch Density Woody",
y = "Richness",
colour = "Patch Density Herbaceous",
title = "") '''
